# SQL LIKE not getting right results

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables  Users & Person

**Users** - username , firstname , lastname , personid

**Person** -  personID ,   Name1 ,  Name2

ForExample:    FirstName:Tom  LastName:Jerry   Name1:TomTom

See in the able example there last name is not found any where in the Name1 column.

I need to pull up all the records in the database in which user table last name does not 
show up in the name1 column of person table.

```
SELECT Users.UserName,Users.FirstName,Users.LastName,
       Users.PersonID,Person.Name1,Person.Name2
FROM Users
JOIN Person
ON Users.PersonID = Person.PersonID
WHERE Users.LastName NOT LIKE  '%'+Person.Name1+'%'
```

But this is not returning me the right set of records.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a record that you say is wrong?

Comment: if you look at the example i provided basically a  I am looking for Name1 to be TomJerry not TomTom

Comment: did you just reverse your fields? It sounds like you're looking for Person.Name1 NOT LIKE '%'+Users.LastName+'%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your logic at the end is wrong.

You want to find all "all the records in the database in which user table last name does not show up in the name1 column of person table."

Your logic as it currently stands is "where last name is not like name1."

What you want is "where name1 does not contain last name."

```
SELECT Users.UserName,
       Users.FirstName,
       Users.LastName,
       Users.PersonID,
       Person.Name1,
       Person.Name2
FROM   Users
JOIN   Person
ON     Users.PersonID = Person.PersonID
WHERE  Users.Name1 NOT LIKE LastName NOT LIKE '%' + LastName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it returning?

Try using Trim() on the string you're searching for, maybe there is whitespace that is causing it to not find a match?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT *
 FROM USER u
 WHERE u.LastName NOT IN (SELECT p.Name1 from Person p)
```

Comment: He needs that the lastname won't be contained in the name, your query finds exact matches.

Comment: @Lamak: OP <<"I need to pull up all the records in the database in which user table last name does not show up in the name1 column of person table.">> - What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
SELECT Users.UserName,Users.FirstName,Users.LastName,Users.PersonID,Person.Name1,Person.Name2
FROM Users, Person
WHERE Users.PersonID = Person.PersonID
AND Users.LastName NOT LIKE  '%'+Person.Name1+'%'
```